# Need to determine if I should use CPT or Custom Post tables in Wordpress

Tags: database, wordpress

I am building a new wordpress plugin that will help my customers manage their products and billing and I am not sure whether I should build custom tables or the wordpress custom post types to complete my solution.

If I were to build custom tables, it would look like this.

**Tables:**

- **Customers** (One to Many with link to wp_users table linking there user accounts on my site.
- **Products** (One to many with link to customers table)
- **Invoices** (Many to many with links to customers table and products table)

Comment: you can install and use the WooCommerce plugin for with same details.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  I'm trying to understand design concepts around CPT's or custom tables.  Also, woo-commerce offers the abiltiy to sell online, but my products are digital and require API calls to get the products so more custom work is needed then just adding woo-commerce.